# Is there a set of well-known tracking parameters besides utm_*?

Tags: query-string, utm-parameters

I am collecting a large number of URLs. I am not responsible for the websites in question, and I want to remove tracking parameters that do not affect the content of the website. With the tracking parameters, it's impossible to identify two URLs that should be considered equal.

For example, if I have the following links:

1. `http://example.com/blog/post1?utm_xyz=1234`
2. `http://example.com/blog/post1?utm_xyz=5678`
3. `http://example.net/viewblog?post_id=2&utm_xyz=9999`

I want to convert to the equivalent canonical-type URLs:

1. `http://example.com/blog/post1`
2. `http://example.com/blog/post1`
3. `http://example.net/viewblog?post_id=2`

The first two are for the same content, but have different tracking parameters. The last example illustrates why I can't just remove all query parameters.

The most common of these are the `utm_` ones, but I have also found:

- Piwik: `pk_campaign` and `pk_kwd`
- WebTrends: `WT.nav`, `WT.mc_id`
- unknown, maybe Apple: `campaign_id`
- Wikimedia: `wprov`
- HootSuite: `hootPostID`

Is there a well-known list of these query parameters that I can safely remove?

(I am using the canonical URLs where they are supplied in the HTML metadata, but I want to use this approach when none is supplied.)

Comment: What do you mean by "safely remove"?   In what context?   Removing these query parameters will obviously break tracking, so why do you want to remove them?

Comment: I'm collecting URLs (I'm doing something similar to running a search engine crawler). I want to remove the tracking parameters from these URLs to create a canonical URL. By 'safely' I mean not remove parameters that will serve different content. For example `post_id` in a blog post URL is important.

Comment: That makes sense.  I know Googlebot auto-ignores the `UTM` tracking parameters.  I'd assume it probably does so for some of the other tracking params as well.   I've never seen a published list of these parameters from any search engine crawler though.    It would certainly be nice to create such a list.

Comment: Agreed. I'm glad I didn't miss something obvious!

Comment: This is a useful question. Wikipedia, for example, [forbids tracking parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:ELNO) in URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Part of my `RewriteCond` used to deduplicate URL for a more efficient caching:
`utm_(?:source|medium|campaign|term|content)|gclid|fbclid|msclkid|emci|emdi|ceid|sourceid|hootPostID|__s`

- [gclid](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=en)
- [fbclid](https://fbclid.com/)
- [msclkid](https://help.ads.microsoft.com/apex/index/3/en/60000)
- [hootPostID](https://help.hootsuite.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008117833-Apply-link-settings) (guessed)
- [__s](https://www.drip.com/learn/docs/manual/email-builder/suppress-__s-from-rendered-links)
- emci/emdi/ceid: Caught from my logs. Maybe from [this](https://www.emcimedia.com/clients)
- sourceid: Caught from my logs

Answer (score 1):

I guess your intention is to clean the scraped URLs.

You can refer to [articles on best practices of using UTM](https://blog.bufferapp.com/utm-guide). Commonly used keywords for `utm_medium` are based on the naming conventions used in Google Analytics such as, social, referral, email.

At the end of the day there is no good way if you’re doing this based on a fixed list of keywords. Because the parameters can be anything.

**You will have a better chance of sanitising your results by using regex to detect and remove any UTM parameters.**

For a URL like `https://example.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=book-launch-2014` you need to search and replace the parameters with *nothing*:

- `utm_source`
- `utm_medium`
- `utm_campaign`
- `utm_term`
- `utm_content`

Comment: The question was, is there a set of well-known tracking parameters _besides_ `utm_*`