# Bing randomly adds MSCLKID parameter to links in SERPs

Tags: url, search-results, bing, url-parameters

When searching Bing recently, I noticed, that links to my websites get automatically appended **MSCLKID** parameter whichs turned out to be some id for analytics or ads-tracking. This resulted in 400 (Bad Request) errors on my sites because I block links with unknown parameters.

Half an hour after discovering, the parameter wasn't added anymore. Weird, however I whitelisted it to prevent further errors and make my sites accessible to Bing visitors, if it happens again.

Anyone else encountered this and do you know if there is an option in Bing WMT? Haven't found one yet. Btw I'm not using any Bing services besides some API and Webmaster Tools. No idea where it came from.

Comment: Maybe it is a tracking parameter?  It is listed in this question: [Is there a set of well-known tracking parameters besides utm_*?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109914/is-there-a-set-of-well-known-tracking-parameters-besides-utm)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hi and thank you for this great collection of tracking parameters! Yes indeed it's listed here as autotagging parameter for Microsoft advertising, but I'm not a customer of this programme, so I wonder why I got added this to outgoing links from Bing serps to my pages and a bit later suddenly the parameter disappeared again.